# How do I use a multidatatrigger to conditionally change the opacity of a different control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I'm having trouble understanding how Datatriggers and Multidatatriggers function. I am assuming they're used for XAML functions conditionally. My problem is as follows:

I would like to use a Multidatatrigger such that when a button is pressed, the opacity of a Wrap panel is reduced from 1 to 0 (presumably using a DoubleAnimation), but only if it is currently visible (Visibility is Visible) and its opacity is currently 1. Once this is done, I would like some sort of completed event to allow me to set Visbility of the wrap panel to collapse in code.

I can figure out how to do the latter but not the former.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```xml
<Image x:Name="btn" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225" Grid.Column="1" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/btn.png">
<Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Opacity}" Value="1" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsVisible}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="wrap_panel_storyboard">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                Storyboard.TargetName="wrap_panel_home_scroller" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                Duration="0:0:1"
                                From="1" To="0"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="wrap_panel_storyboard"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Image.Style>
</Image>

<WrapPanel x:Name="wrap_panel" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">    
</WrapPanel>
```

Now I have absolutely no idea what the 'condition binding' lines do or how to attach them to the variables I want in the wrap panel. I'm not sure what the binding path is or why {} are used there, and because of this I have no idea how to make this multidatatrigger use the wrap panel opacity and visibility as conditions for their execution.

I would appreciate some pointers or be shown how this could be accomplished!

EDIT: If I had to write pseudocode for what I'm trying to accomplish it would  be as follows:

```
On Image.Click:
 If Panel.Opacity = 1 And Panel.Visible = True Then
  RunAnimation
 End If
```

The image this style is applied to and the panel which is being evaluated are two seperate controls

Below is the grid markup with the places of the controls within preserved.

```
        <Grid x:Name="grid_parent">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="grid_child"  Height="70" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="1200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>            

            <Image x:Name="btn" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="225" Grid.Column="1" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/btn.png">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
                <Image.Triggers>
                </Image.Triggers>
            </Image>
          </Grid>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="wrap_panel_scroller" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="{x:Null}">
            <WrapPanel x:Name="wrap_panel" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">                    
            </WrapPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: There is a subtle difference between `MultiDataTrigger` and `MultiTrigger`.
When you check conditions on properties of the UI element, like `Opacity` or `IsVisible` then you should (must) use MultiTrigger.
If you work on properties of the DataContext/ViewModel then you'll use a `MultiDataTrigger`. So in your case you need a `MultiTrigger` not a `MultiDataTrigger`

Comment: In general a trigger is the XAML version of a condition, just like an If-statement in code.
A multitrigger checks multiple conditions, like an if statement with AND/ANDALSO in VB.NET.
Checking if Opacity is 1 or IsVisible is true is a little odd, because the default value for opacity is 1 (opacity is the opposite of transparency btw). IsVisible defaults to true unless you haven't set Visibility to hidden or collapsed before.

Usually a trigger/multitrigger specifies a condition that might occur under certain circumstances when the app is running but not under the default startup conditions

Comment: "*I have absolutely no idea what the 'condition binding' lines do*", "*what the binding path is or why {} are used there*" - have you considered taking a look at the documentation? Perhaps start here: [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-5.0)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to trigger an animations based on property values of the `Image` that the `Style` is being applied to, you should replace the `MultiDataTrigger` with a `MultiTrigger`:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
        <Condition Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="wrap_panel_storyboard">
            ...
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
</MultiTrigger>
```

You should also remove the `ExitAction` since you animate the property to a value different than 1 that you trigg on. This means that the exit action will trigger as soon as the animation has begun and the `Opacity` property has been animated to a new value between 1 and 0.

If you want to trigger the animation based on the property values of another element, you should stick to using a `MultiDataTrigger`:

```
<MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Binding="{Binding Opacity, ElementName=wrap_panel_storyboard}" Value="1" />
    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsVisible,ElementName=wrap_panel_storyboard}" Value="True" />
</MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
```

This requires the `WrapPanel` and the `Image` to reside in the same [namescope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

Also note that an animation that applies to the `WrapPanel` should be defined in a `Style` that is applied to the `WrapPanel` and not in a `Style` that is applied to an `Image`.

Comment: Thank you but I'm trying to trigger animations ased on property values of a different control (the wrap_panel) and not the image that the style is being applied to. The image only serves as a button

Comment: So where is the `WrapPanel` in your example?

Comment: Apologies, I have added the wrap panel XAML in my post.

Comment: It' still unclear where the `Image` that the style is being applied to is located.

Comment: I am unsure as to what you're asking. The `WrapPanel` and `Image` are both children of a `Grid` Control. The `Image` is not placed inside the `WrapPanel`

Comment: Why do you use an image style to animate a `WrapPanel`...? By the way, see my edit.

Comment: I have added the `Grid` markup. I attempted to try and animate the `WrapPanel` using the `Image` the same way I animated the `Image` opacity when the `Image` is clicked, and assumed the style would then be attached to the control that was being interacted with.

Comment: When exactly you want to apply the animation?

Comment: On  `MouseDown`, when I changed the Image's own opacity using an 'EventTrigger', the RoutedEvent was `<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseDown">` , but this approach does not seem to work when manipulating the wrappanel with the image.

Comment: No, an image style cannot modify a `WrapPanel`.